# Solving for the Exponent Value in an Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I need to solve the following equation:

> $1.024^t = 2$

I cannot use logarithms to solve for $t$ because we haven't formally learned it in class yet. Is there another way to solve for $t$? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that decimal point in the original question?

Comment: Are you using $.$ as a separator for $1024$?

Comment: I needed to solve for $t$ in the following equation: $5280(1.024)^t = 10560$. From that, I got $1.024^t = 2$. The $.$ is a decimal point.

Comment: One way or another logarithms appear. You may use $1.024 = \frac{2^{10}}{10^3} = \frac{2^7}{5^3},$ but later you need some $b$ with $2^b = 5,$ or some $c$ with $5^c = 2$

Comment: How else will you do it?

Comment: Just curious, what was the answer graded as "right"?

Comment: $t$ was around 29 years or so. Since I don't know how to use $\log$ yet, I had to either do guess-and-check or graph the exponential function and $y = 2$ and find the intersection of the two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way to solve for $t$?

Short Answer: No.

Long Answer: You will not be able to reach an *exact answer* to this without the usage of logarithms, as the answer is irrational. The concepts of  logarithms are not hard to understand.

You can simply take $\log_{1.024}$ on both sides, so $t=\log_{1.024}2$. If $\log_{1.024}2$ seems ugly and you want your answer to be in terms of just $\log$(which is $\log_{10}$), you can use the [logarithmic base change rule](http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm) to get:$$t=\dfrac{\log 2}{\log 1.024}$$

Answer (score 1):

First I’m going to assume that the question is $1024^t = 2$ because that is more likely the problem being asked.

My first step would be to calculate the powers of 2. $2^1 = 2$, $2^2 = 2$ $...$. Until I got $2^{10} = 1024$.  Knowing this I would reframe the question as.

$$(2^{10})^t = 2^1$$
$$2^{10t} = 2^1$$
$$ 10t = 1$$
$$ t = \frac{1}{10} $$

If the question is “1.024” then the question gets harder.

$(2^{10}10^{-3})^t = 2^1$

Now I just happen to know that $2^{3.32...} = 10$ but if you didn’t know that then there is no way to work this out without using logs.

$$(2^{10}(2^{3.32...})^{-3})^t = 2^1$$
$$(2^{10}2^{-9.96...})^t = 2^1$$
$$2^{(0.04...)t} = 2^1 $$
$$ (0.04...)t = 1$$
$$ t \approx 25$$

However given that finding the solution requires you to already happen to know the logarithm of 10 base 2 I’m going to suggest you metagame the question you have been given and check if you haven’t made a mistake in your calculations leading up to this point.